# What is the best state management choice for maintaining a large datatable during postback in a vb.net application used by multiple people?

Tags: .net, vb.net, session, postback, viewstate

I am currently building an application in vb.net that deals with datatables of various sizes - could be 100 results, could be 100,000 - and displays them in an asp gridview. The app will be available on the web so I suspect it will be used by multiple users at once.

I need some sort of state management protocol to manage the data in between postbacks. What is the best way to accomplish this without hindering performance?

We are currently using session, but the problem is that the session will sometimes timeout unexpectedly. (I have read that regular security checks on the server can sometimes trigger a postback, thus the user's data will be lost!)

Alternatively, I've tried viewstate, but this causes a long pause when the user pages through the gridview containing the datatable, so I had to rule that out.

The literature on the topic doesnt offer a clear solution to my issue. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean a results of 100,000 rows into a gridview? How is that even possible?
(it is not).
As for session() being blown out? Just adopt SQL server based session - turn it on, it is automatic, no code changes required, and is 100% dead bullet proof. Memory based session is problem matic, since often any code execution error on the site by ANY client user can cause a app pool error, and your session() is the blown out of the water. (but not with SQL server based sessions - so turn that feature on and this issue s gone gone.).

However this is like looking at some medicne to kill the patient (keeping session), and that of 100,000 rows being returned to the client side?

No, that's not how computers work. And it not how even desktop computer software works, let alone web based.

Until you explain why on earth there is even SOME considering of wanting to pull down 100,000 rows of data to the client, then this discussion is dead in the water. In fact BEYOND dead in the water.

Now, you might of course pre-process that data into some useable format for the client side. Say a cool dashboard display for some kind of say auto accident results display. Your source data could even be MUCH more then 100,000 rows, but that data NEVER going to be out of the blue just transferred down to the client side.

You have to make a SUPER case, a beyond logical sound argument that some reason exists for the end user to pull down that much data.

However, some good custom server side routines - even a combination of SQL store procedures, and even have sql calling some custom .net assemblies for some of that processing is possible here.

And writing code against 100,000 rows? Golly, that's going to run VERY fast, and is not really a big data set at all. But trying to deal with, and send such data down to the client side, work with the data, and potential have to send it back up to the server on a post-back? Sorry, that's not going to work here.

I mean, one possible approach would I suppose is to consider Blazer. This would allow you to send the table to the client side, (100,000 rows), and then at that point work on that data 100% client side, but then again, even that's stretching's things here. But then again. Blazer means you would have to drop asp.net + web forms (and also (sadly) vb.net, and jump to c#).

I mean, in the past, when have you ever had to deal with 100,000 rows in some kind of grid, and how on earth was it possible for the user to even scroll, or deal with such data?
Answer:
You provided a UI in which the user can enter criteria, perhaps search, and THEN display the results of that search.

So the answer to your problem?

It's not a problem of session() - adopt SQL server based sessions (just turn it on) and that issue is gone gone.

but, the 100,000 rows into a grid? Well, that don't make sense, and it rare makes sense in ANY software designed system I can think of.

But,  yes, Blazer - client side is a possible solution here, since the data once downloaded could be worked with 100% client side without any real server side interaction required from that point on wards.

Edit:

Now it is possbille that you mean the table is 100,000 rows (that is a tiny database), and that you want to query or pull data from that table into a grid - not all 100,000 rows. Well, that's a 100% different question and issue.
And the answer is simple:
provide some UI for the user to select or filter or enter criteria before you pull down the data. I mean, a database can have millions of rows for say orders on a whole country. But pulling orders for one city? Probably a 1000 or so - so that's just fine.

The table data sizes don't matter much, 100,000 rows, or even 5,000,0000 rows as long as you ONLY pulling from those tables some kind of filtered datasets, and thus performance will and should be just fine.

Comment: The user is able to page and sort the table so the data has to persist between postbacks for at least 20 to 30 minutes.

Comment: but if you are paging and filtering, then say 40 rows per page - I don't see the issue then? Adding paging and a page control to that grid means only a screen full of records need be pulled. -- thus the gridview built in state management should be just fine here.